# Segmentation Fault en un array y error en un bucle

Tags: c++

soy nuevo por aquí. Estudio 1º de Ingeniería Informática, y utilizo C++ en Fundamentos de Programación.

Pues bien, estoy resolviendo este ejercicio (lo pongo como imagen porque es bastante lioso):

[image: Ejercicio a resolver]

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

const int NCIUDADES = 8;

void hazRuta(const int kilometros [][NCIUDADES], int ciudadActual, int ruta[]){
    bool visitados [NCIUDADES];
    for (int j = 0; j < NCIUDADES; j++)
        visitados[j] = false;
    int distanciaMenor, ciudadDMenor, contadorRuta = 0;
    while (contadorRuta < NCIUDADES){
        distanciaMenor = kilometros[0][ciudadActual];
        for (int i = 0; i < NCIUDADES; i++){
            if (i == ciudadActual)
                continue;
            if (kilometros[i][ciudadActual] < distanciaMenor && visitados[i] == false){
                distanciaMenor = kilometros[i][ciudadActual];
                ciudadDMenor = i;
            }
        }
        ruta[contadorRuta] = ciudadDMenor;
        contadorRuta++;
        visitados[ciudadDMenor] = true;
        ciudadActual = ciudadDMenor;
    }
}

int main (){
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Spanish");
    //Ciudades:  0-Almería, 1-Cádiz, 2-Córdoba, 3-Granada, 4-Huelva, 5-Jaén, 6-Málaga y 7-Sevilla
    int kilometros [NCIUDADES][NCIUDADES] = {{0, 615, 364, 166, 608, 283, 210, 503},{615, 0, 268, 347, 248, 360, 268, 145},{364, 268, 0, 200, 236, 105, 172, 133}
                                            ,{166, 347, 200, 0, 373, 91, 164, 269},{608, 248, 236, 373, 0, 335, 318, 96},{283, 360, 105, 91, 335, 0, 236, 234}
                                            ,{210, 268, 172, 164, 318, 236, 0, 215},{503, 145, 133, 269, 96, 234, 215, 0}};
    int partida, ruta [NCIUDADES];

    cout << "Introduzca el número de la ciudad de partida (0-Almería, 1-Cádiz, 2-Córdoba, 3-Granada, 4-Huelva, 5-Jaén, 6-Málaga y 7-Sevilla): ";
    cin >> partida;
    while (partida < 0 || partida > 7){
        cout << "Número no válido. Reintrodúzcalo: ";
        cin >> partida;
    }

    hazRuta(kilometros, partida, ruta);

    cout << "La ruta para visitar todas las ciudades es: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < NCIUDADES; i++){
        cout << ruta[i] << ", ";
    }
    cout << endl;



system("Pause");
return 0;
}
```

Para empezar, si como ciudad de partida elijo la 0, se produce el error "Segmentation Fault", cosa que me ha pasado alguna vez trabajando con punteros, pero que no comprendo en un simple array de tamaño fijo.

Por otro lado, si como punto de partida elijo otra ciudad, el programa se ejecuta, pero el resultado es a todas luces incorrecto. Por ejemplo, para la ciudad 6 recibo el resultado:

```
3, 5, 2, 7, 4, 1, 6, 6
```

Seguramente sea absurdo, pero soy incapaz de encontrar el error.

Agradezco cualquier ayuda, pero por favor tengan en cuanta que solo estoy empezando en este terreno.

Muchas gracias.
Un saludo.

Comment: +1 ¡ Da gusto ver esta pregunta ! Código mínimo, reproducible, descripción del problema, comportamiento observado y esperado ... Llegarás lejos aquí :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## El problema para la ciudad 0

En tu función `hazRuta()` tienes esta línea:

```
  while (contadorRuta < NCIUDADES){
        distanciaMenor = kilometros[0][ciudadActual];
        ...
  }
```

Es decir, inicializas `distanciaMenor` como la distancia entre la ciudad 0 y la ciudad actual. Pero si la ciudad actual es la ciudad 0, ¡la distancia será 0! ¡Por tanto ninguna otra ciudad va a lograr una distancia mejor! Así que `ciudadMenor` queda sin inicializar y cuando intentas después hacer `visitados[ciudadMenor] = true`, ya tienes un segfault puesto que `ciudadMenor` puede tener cualquier valor arbitrario.

A mi no me produce fallo de segmentación, porque mi compilador inicializa a 0 por defecto las variables, de modo que `ciudadMenor` queda con el valor 0 al salir del bucle. Pero esto tampoco arregla el problema, pues elegirá la ciudad 0 como ciudad a la que viajar, y volverá a repetir el bucle partiendo de nuevo desde esa misma ciudad. Así genera la "ruta óptima" 0, 0, 0, 0, 0... hasta que `contadorRuta` alcanza el valor `NCIUDADES` y entonces deja de iterar.

### Posible solución

Puedes inicializar `distanciaMenor` con un valor arbitrariamente grande, que sea mayor que el de la distancia a cualquier otra ciudad, como por ejemplo la constante `INT_MAX` (predefinida en `limits.h`). O, como menciona Trauma en un comentario, por el valor `std::numeric_limits< int >::max( );` (requiere `#include <limits>`). O si prefieres define tú una constante `MAX_DISTANCIA` y dale un valor grande como 10000 (mayor a cualquiera de las distancias de la matriz).

## Otras ciudades

El fallo antes mencionado afecta a cualquier otra ciudad de partida tan pronto como la ruta alcance la ciudad 0, pues en ese caso de nuevo `distanciaMenor` es cero, inmejorable, y no se actualiza`ciudadMenor`, que por tanto mantiene el valor que tenía en la iteración anterior del bucle. Por eso se te repite al final la ciudad 6, cuando debería terminar la ruta en la ciudad 0.

Una vez hecha la corrección anterior a mi me da la ruta:

```
3, 5, 2, 7, 4, 1, 6, 0,
```

Answer (score 3):

Respondiendo a tu pregunta:
1. El segmentation fault es porque distanciaMenor la inicializar con Kilometros[0][ciudadActual] y si ciudadActual es 0, entonces, la distanciaMenor siempre será 0, por lo tanto, ciudadDMenor (que no está inicializada) la utilizaras como indice en visitados[ciudadDMenor]. Para corregir esto, cambia la linea: distanciaMenor=kilometros[0][ciudadActual] por distanciaMenor=999999;

2. Luego, las rutas no es que te salgan erradas, sino es que estas asignando los visitados incorrectamente:

   - la linea: ruta[contadorRuta]=ciudadDMenor debería ser: ruta[contadorRuta] = ciudadActual; ya que es la ciudadActual desde donde has salido.
   - Igualmente la linea: visitados[ciudadDMenor]=true; debería ser: visitados[ciudadActual]=true; ya ciudadActual es la que acabas de visitar.

Tu programa quedaría asi:

```
   #include <iostream>
#include <locale>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

const int NCIUDADES = 8;

void hazRuta( int kilometros[][NCIUDADES], int ciudadActual, int ruta[]) {
    bool visitados[NCIUDADES];
    for (int j = 0; j < NCIUDADES; j++)
       visitados[j] = false;
        int distanciaMenor = 0,ciudadDMenor =0, contadorRuta = 0;
        while (contadorRuta < NCIUDADES) {
         //distanciaMenor = kilometros[0][ciudadActual];
            distanciaMenor = 999999;
            for (int i = 0; i < NCIUDADES; i++) {
                if (i == ciudadActual)
                  continue;
                if (kilometros[i][ciudadActual] < distanciaMenor &&   visitados[i] == false) {
                    distanciaMenor = kilometros[i][ciudadActual];
                    ciudadDMenor = i;
                    }
            }
            ruta[contadorRuta] = ciudadActual;
            contadorRuta++;
            visitados[ciudadActual] = true;
            ciudadActual = ciudadDMenor;
        }
  }

   int main() {
        setlocale(LC_ALL, "Spanish");
//Ciudades:  0-Almería, 1-Cádiz, 2-Córdoba, 3-Granada, 4-Huelva, 5-Jaén, 6-Málaga y 7-Sevilla
int kilometros[NCIUDADES][NCIUDADES] = { {0, 615, 364, 166, 608, 283, 210, 503},{615, 0, 268, 347, 248, 360, 268, 145},{364, 268, 0, 200, 236, 105, 172, 133}
                                        ,{166, 347, 200, 0, 373, 91, 164, 269},{608, 248, 236, 373, 0, 335, 318, 96},{283, 360, 105, 91, 335, 0, 236, 234}
                                        ,{210, 268, 172, 164, 318, 236, 0, 215},{503, 145, 133, 269, 96, 234, 215, 0} };
int partida, ruta[NCIUDADES];

cout << "Introduzca el número de la ciudad de partida (0-Almería, 1-Cádiz, 2-Córdoba, 3-Granada, 4-Huelva, 5-Jaén, 6-Málaga y 7-Sevilla): ";
cin >> partida;
while (partida < 0 || partida > 7) {
    cout << "Número no válido. Reintrodúzcalo: ";
    cin >> partida;
}

hazRuta(kilometros, partida, ruta);

cout << "La ruta para visitar todas las ciudades es: ";
for (int i = 0; i < NCIUDADES; i++) {
    cout << ruta[i] << ", ";
}
cout << endl;



system("Pause");
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Me parece genial una respuesta basada en un algoritmo es una visión de comprender el problema, sin embargo pequeño detalle, hay un error que el OP esta exponiendo en su pregunta y que también sería conveniente explicar como corregir, *el que dice segmentation deafult*

Comment: Perdón el algoritmo esta en base a la ciudad destino. Voy a cambiar. Pero no es tan diferente.